# Leverage browser caching - get caching methods right

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, fingerprinting

I'm trying to get the browser caching right. I added this to my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I'm having the typical problem though that when updating my site, which I do quite frequently, the site doesn't update for frequent visitors. I started using **URL fingerprinting** for my CSS files, which works well.

However, what can I do about HTML files?

Any best practice to not run into caching troubles when updating content on any pages? I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the correct strategy (and the one used by HTML5Boilerplate) is to *disable* caching for HTML files, by setting the Expires time to `access plus 0 seconds`.